# Vue.js proxying

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to setup a proxy to be able to use relative path instead of declaring full host name, since my backend works on another port. Here is what my `vue.config.js` looks like:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': '',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

`vue.config.js` gets loaded, but when I try to send a request to `/api/auth/pass`, implying it to be converted to `http://localhost:8080/auth/pass` (my backend works on 8080), it gets sent to `http://localhost:8080/api/auth/pass`. Here is my javascript method to send a POST request:

```
async submitForm () {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/auth/pass', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(this.formData)
        })
        /*here comes response handling*/
    }
```

How do I make this request to be sent to port 8080 using the proxy instead?

Edit: I made a typo in the last sentence… I want this proxy to send the request to 8080, where the backend is listening, not 8081, where vuejs is serving.

Comment: Do you get the correct response? It's unclear what's the problem exactly and whether you understand how proxy works correctly, the description of the problem is vague. "How do I make this request to be sent to port 8081" - as long as Vue app is localhost:8081, fetch('/api/auth/pass') makes a request to localhost:8081/api/auth/pass, and it's passed to  localhost:8080/auth/pass by a proxy

Comment: perhaps the issue is you don't know what `devServer` is configuring - your fetch will be sent to port 8081 when running a development server (`npm run serve` if using the old vue-cli-service), in fact every request will, since that's where you've configured your dev server to run. i.e. You'd be loading your project `http://localhost:8081` in your browser, tight? However, any requests to `/api/....` will be proxied to `http://localhost:8080` as per your configuration

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, I made a typo, making my question pointless. Your last sentence is what I’m trying to achieve, however, the request is sent to http://localhost:8081/api/…, hence no substitution is made for some reason.

Comment: that made it less clear

Comment: @JaromandaX The proxy is configured to „replace“ the call to /api/… with http://localhost:8080/… However, request is sent to http://localhost:8081/api… Port 8081 is a port, where my vue app is serving, hence, the request to /api isn’t „redirected“ to/replaced with/proxied to http://localhost:8080

Comment: …what probably brought me to Stackoverflow

Comment: @ArliChokoev See the first comment, it's explained. You make a request to the proxy, then the proxy makes a request to the backend, should be visible in logs. It's supposed  to work the way you did it. But it's unclear what are your expectations, the question lacks clear problem statement